# Macbook pro OSX stuck in version 10.9.1, can't update software

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

I've tried updating my software to 10.9.2 and 10.9.3, but it won't go. After trying to install it and restarting my laptop, I am still stuck on version 10.9.1. My app store says I should check my purchases again because updates failed. Apps such as iTunes, Pages and others also do not work anymore.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which model of MacBook Pro do you have?

Comment: 13-inch, Mid 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible solution in your case can be doing a combo update, but this may erase all the data from your drive.

Comment: I have done a combo update, but it still doesn't work. When I restart my laptop again, it says "updates aren't installed"

Comment: How are you doing the update can you tell me?

Comment: I check for software updates and then click install whenever there is one in the app store. It starts installing and then when it restarts, it says updates were not installed

Comment: That is a Delta update, Download the Combo Update from here http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1746 and see if this works.

Comment: I have tried. When my laptop restarted, there's a notification that says "Updates not installed, some updates could not be installed automaticallly"

Comment: Ok, how did you install a combo update can you tell that to me?

Comment: I clicked on the link that you sent me. After downloading it, I waited for my laptop to tell me to restart my laptop so it can finish installing. But when it restarted, nothing changed, and my laptop notified me that updates were not installed

Comment: Ok, restart you system, as soon as you hear the Chime sound press the "option key" and hold, then select the recovery, next Click on reinstall OSX, If that doesn't work, Use this guide (http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/11807/os-x-lion-convert-os-x-lion-dmg-installer-to-a-bootable-usb-thumbdrive-install-without-an-optical-drive/) to make it a Bootable USB drive and repeat the steps from pressing the "option key" onwards.

Comment: @thisisprb this is a makeshift solution. it still doesn't solve the underlying issue that your Apple ID is either not tied to the purchased apps on your machine, or it is, and it's still failing to properly 'shake hands' with Apple's servers. The problem will re-occur once another update is rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign out of the App Store under Store > Sign out (in it's menu bar)
2. Sign back into it with your Apple ID and Password
3. Attempt the update again following re-authenitication